# Configure pom.xml for hibernate 3.6

Tags: hibernate, maven, pom.xml, java

I've tried to configure `pom.xml` file for my `Spring 3` and `Hibernate 3.6` application.
The relevant part of `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.17.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Nevertheless, if I don't include `javassist.jar` library directly to my buildpath as an `External jar`, I keep getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. Is there anything wrong in my `pom.xml`, due it doesn't download this dependency when building the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `hibernate-entitymanager` instead of `hibernate-core`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This will include all necessary dependencies transitively. Check maven dependency hierarchy after you make this change.

BTW the lastest available version of hibernate in maven central is 4.1.18

Comment: so if I'll change it to `hibernate-entitymanager` then I can delete all other dependencies, that are below that dependency?

Comment: yes, entitymanager will add core, javassisst and other needed for Hibernate. Note that they will be consistent versions

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException should also mention the name of class which was not found.

1. First you verify the jar you are trying to copy is getting copied into the build path or not.
2. If 1 is yes, then expand the javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar to check if the missing class file for which you got exception is present or not.

The external jar which resolves the issues, try to find out its version, maybe you can get it from MANIFEST.MF file of that jar.

May be something was refactored which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```